# Remove special characters python

Tags: python, dataframe

I’m trying to remove special characters, but the dataframe just prints the same content without removing special characters.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

movies = pd.read_csv(‘Moviesreviews.csv')
movies['original_title’] = movies[‘title’] + movies ['overview']

movies["original_title"] = movies["original_title"]

temp_str = ''

temp_str=re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9 \n\.]', '', temp_str)

movies.head()
```

Comment: Which column do you want to remove special characters from? Which characters are "special characters"?

Comment: Can you [edit] to include sample input and expected output to make a [mcve]?

Comment: For start: `movies["original_title"] = movies["original_title"]` is doing nothing. Then `temp_str=re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9 \n\.]', '', temp_str)` is doing regex sub on empty string.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

movies = pd.read_csv('Moviesreviews.csv')
movies['original_title'] = movies['title'] + movies ['overview']
movies["original_title_clean"] = movies["original_title"].str.replace(r'\W', '', regex=True)

movies.head()
```